# How to filter image list with twig in grav

Tags: twig, grav

I am inserting a list of sponsor images in a sidebar in grav and want to show only images starting with `sponsor_`.

At the moment, my code adds any image in the page folder.

base.html.twig:

```
<div class="sidebar-right-content">
<!-- insert R sidebar images here     -->

<div class="sponsor-image">
  <h3>Sponsors</h3>
    {% for image in page.media.images %}
      <br>{{ image.html }}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have tried restricting the images returned by using the expression below, but no images are returned:

```
{% for image in page.media.images if image matches '/^sponsor.*$/' %}
```

Is there a way to use a filter in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing of a few options, I found a somewhat inelegant way to solve this problem.
The main thing to undertand is that `page.media.images` returns an array, so we can't filter this as a string.
So I just nested a match statement.  I wonder if there's a one-liner solution.

```
{% for image in page.media.images %}
    {% if image.html matches '/.*sponsor.*$/' %}
    <br>{{ image.html }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this input! For me, the `.html` method did not work for the regex comparison. However, when I changed it to `.url`, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

try: `{% image in page.media.images |contains('sponsor') %}`

Comment: grav doesn't seem to like that syntax, it throws an error:  0 - An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given") in "partials/base.html.twig" at line 96.